# Toggle specific li div

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

```
<li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com " target="_blank"> goto yahoo.</a>
<span id="comment"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26715029/img/fc.jpg"       style="vertical-align:middle" width="20" height="20" alt="fc"/>| or comment about yahoo</span>
<div class="commentbox">
<div id="fb-root">coment box is here</div>

</div>

</li>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com " target="_blank"> go to google </a>
<span id="comment"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26715029/img/fc.jpg"  style="vertical-align:middle" width="20" height="20" alt="fc"/>or comment about google</span>
<div class="commentbox">

</div>

</li>
```

Need to  toggle specific li div, not both. Tried accordion but link does not work. 
FYI: The list is much larger
http://jsfiddle.net/NQw5L/18/

Answer (score 0):

IDs **must** be unique. If you convert them to a class, you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.comment').click(function () {
        $(this).next('.commentbox').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NQw5L/19/)**

Comment: It is not neccessary to change to classes, you can just use: $('span[id=comment]')

Comment: @debute - Yes, it is. IDs **must** be unique. If they're not, then they're both invalid, and pointless to use as IDs.

Comment: I know, of course. But when he need (maybe not in this code) to use IDs, this is the way.

Comment: Thanks for feed back guys...The code works great but got load time problem. The comment box I'm loading is facebook comment box with large list. Is there way to load the FB comment when clicked on icon. As of now the comment box is hidden in css. I realized this is not gonna work.  http://rabbletrends.com/

Answer (score 0):

j08691 is right, but if you dont want to do that manually - try setting the class instead of the id and using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cCtr=0;
    $('.commentbox').each (function() {
       $(this).attr('id','comment'+cCtr++); 
    });
    var cCtr=0;
    $('.comment').each (function() {
       $(this).attr('data-targ', 'comment'+cCtr++);
    });

    $('.comment').click(function() {
        var slId = $(this).attr('data-targ');
        $('#'+slId).slideToggle("slow");

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RHsxG/3/

Comment: ah I hadnt refreshed, the $(this).next is more elegant.